# maintain distance between axis ticks in d3 chart

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js

I am trying to draw a chart using d3-js. I want X axis values to be `[0.25yrs; 0.50yrs; 1yr; 2yrs; 5 yrs; 10yrs; 15yrs; 20yrs; 30 yrs; 50 yrs]`. This can be done using d3's `tickValues()` & `tickFormat()` functions. But I need to maintain certain distance between 0.25, 0.50 & 1 year ticks, because most values belong to these years & more distance between them will reduce overlapping of drawn circles.

The tick position I need is something like : 
[image]

You can see the distance between .01 and .02 in above image. How can we do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to implement a custom scale that maps your input range to this non-uniform output range. Then you can give this scale to your axis and it will draw the ticks accordingly.

You could have a look at the scales that D3 provides if anything is close enough to what you want (a log scale maybe?), but if you can't find anything you have no choice but to implement your own.